# Not able to find cookie for Forms Auth

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have two pages login.aspx and cookie.aspx

When the user logs in it's suppose to create a cookie and redirect to cookie.aspx.  When cookie.aspx loads it suspose to check if the cookie exists.

Here is my login.aspx login code

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    userName = Login1.UserName;
    passWord = Login1.Password;

    athUser = DirectoryServicesProcessor.Verify_User(userName, passWord);
    if (athUser == true)
    {
        //FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);
        bool IsPersistentCookie = true;
        DateTime expirationDate = new DateTime();
        if (IsPersistentCookie)
            expirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        else
            expirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(300); 

        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1,
            userName,
            DateTime.Now,
            expirationDate,
            IsPersistentCookie,
            userName,
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

        string et = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, et);
        if (IsPersistentCookie)
            cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
        cookie.Name = ".AUTH";
        cookie.Domain = ".mydomain.com";
        Response.SetCookie(cookie);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        Response.Redirect("~/cookietest/cookie.aspx");
    }
```

Here is my pageload for cookie.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);

    if (cookie != null)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

        if (ticket != null)
        {
            WhatHappened.Text = "Found the cookie!";
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("../failure.aspx");
        }
    }
    else
    {

        Response.Redirect("../failure.aspx");
    }

}
```

I'm wondering why cookie.aspx cannot find the cookie created in login.aspx.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use `FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName` to set the cookie name.

```
cookie.Name = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
```

For me, that is set to `.ASPXAUTH` not `.AUTH`.

Comment: Daniel - that didnt make a difference.  I'm also in debug mode in VS is that matters but I dont think it does.

Comment: can you see what cookie the browser is getting?

Comment: Daniel - the cookie name is getting set to ASP.Net_SessionID

Comment: Daniel - it seems to only be creating the session cookie not the forms auth cookie.

Comment: @Mike then theres a problem with creating the cookie.

Comment: @Mike the cookie.path property.

Comment: path="/" protection="Validation" slidingExpiration="false" name=".ASPXAUTH"